# Snowflake NULL_IF on COPY TO from S3 doesn't work

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

`s3://data/snowflake/warehouse/exports/scheduled__2023-01-17T16:40:00+00:00/export.json`:

```
{"START_TIME": "2023-01-04T01:00:00", "END_TIME": "2023-01-04T16:30:00", "EXPORT_CHANNEL": "EXPORT_ADHOC", "PROJECT_ID": "None"}
```

Creating STAGE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY STAGE "export_scheduled__2023-01-17T16:40:00+00:00" 
    url='s3://data/snowflake/warehouse/exports/scheduled__2023-01-17T16:40:00+00:00/export.json'
    storage_integration = OPS_INT 
    file_format = (type = JSON, NULL_IF = ('None')) 
    copy_options = (MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME=CASE_INSENSITIVE,FORCE=TRUE,ON_ERROR='ABORT_STATEMENT')
```

Query of copying data from S3 to Snowflake:

```
COPY INTO "EXPORT" FROM @"export_scheduled__2023-01-17T16:40:00+00:00"
```

Error:

> Failed to cast variant value "None" to FIXED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL_IF` option seems to be ignored for columns that are defined on the target table as NUMBER.

Reproducible case:

```
-- input JSON loaded into user stage
COPY INTO @~
FROM (SELECT PARSE_JSON('{"START_TIME": "2023-01-04T01:00:00",
                          "END_TIME": "2023-01-04T16:30:00",
                          "EXPORT_CHANNEL": "EXPORT_ADHOC",
                          "PROJECT_ID": "None"}') as col)
FILE_FORMAT=(TYPE=JSON)
OVERWRITE = TRUE;

LIST @~;
-- data_0_0_0.json.gz
```

Target table with `PROJECT_ID` column defined as **TEXT**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE target(START_TIME DATETIME, 
                               END_TIME DATETIME, 
                               EXPORT_CHANNEL TEXT, 
                               PROJECT_ID TEXT);

COPY INTO target
FROM  @~/data_0_0_0.json.gz
file_format = (type = JSON, NULL_IF = ('None'))
MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME =CASE_INSENSITIVE ;

SELECT * FROM target;
```

Output: Loaded correctly, NULL_IF option replaced `None` to `NULL`.

[image]

---

Target table with `PROJECT_ID` column defined as **INT**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE target(START_TIME DATETIME, 
                               END_TIME DATETIME, 
                               EXPORT_CHANNEL TEXT, 
                               PROJECT_ID INT);

COPY INTO target
FROM  @~/data_0_0_0.json.gz
file_format = (type = JSON, NULL_IF = ('None'))
MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME =CASE_INSENSITIVE;
```

Output:

> Failed to cast variant value "None" to FIXED

---

Using transformation during load(warning! MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME is not supported and columns have to be specified **explicitly**)

Also explicit usage of `TRY_TO_NUMBER` to handle incorrect `None` value cast to INT.

```
COPY INTO target(START_TIME, END_TIME, EXPORT_CHANNEL, PROJECT_ID)
FROM  (SELECT $1:START_TIME::DATETIME, 
              $1:END_TIME::DATETIME, 
              $1:EXPORT_CHANNEL::TEXT, 
              TRY_TO_NUMBER($1:PROJECT_ID::TEXT)
       FROM @~/data_0_0_0.json.gz)
file_format = (type = JSON, NULL_IF = ('None'));

SELECT * FROM target;
```

Output:

[image]