# Snowflake external table that sits over csv files, not handling nulls as expected

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, file-format, external-tables

I have many external tables that sits over csv files in S3. I have string values in numeric columns that should be parsed as null, e.g. 'na'. when I query the stage with the file format, this works as expected. However when using in external table get an error "failed to case variant valie "na" to FIXED. anyone able to help me understand why this is the case?

```
create or replace file format csv_format
type = csv
field_delimiter = '||'
skip_header=1
encoding='ISO-8859-15'
null_if = 'na'
field_optionally_enclosed_by = '"'


create or replace external table ext_tbl(
    col1 data as (value:c1::date)
    ,col2 number(18,2) as (value:c2::number(18,2)
)
location=@stage
file_format = 'csv_format';
```

My tables are 100s of columns so I dont want to have to go down the nullif in the column definition.

Comment: I’m guessing that there are values other than ‘na’ in that column that cannot be cast as FIXED e.g. ‘na ‘. Try querying the stage for values like this (I.e. not null but try_to_decimal or try_to_number returns null)

Comment: yes there are others like 'no', 'not' etc

Comment: So obviously those values can’t be cast as numbers, hence the error

Comment: would they not be read as nulls though?

Comment: Why would they be read as nulls? The only value you’ve said should be read as null is ‘na’

Comment: I think we are not understanding each other here so in my example above ignore the other string values I mentioned. 'na' isn't being read as null as specified by the file format

Comment: @em456 Based on error message `"failed to case variant value "na" to FIXED` and `null_if = 'na'` it seems to be similar use case [Snowflake NULL_IF on COPY TO from S3 doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75151274/5070879).  I.e. NULL_IF is not applied to NUMBER columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to rely on `NULL_IF` option that may not work for `NUMBER` data type, the alternative is to explicitly cast using `TRY_CAST`:

```
create or replace external table ext_tbl(
     col1 date as (value:c1::date)
    ,col2 number(18,2) as (TRY_CAST(value:c2::TEXT AS number(18,2)))
)
location=@stage
file_format = 'csv_format';
```

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75151274/5070879